How to reset uv editing tab settings?

I was trying to give a wood material to a barrel but I kind of messed up the uv editing part and I was wondering how to reset it so I can do it again from scratch. also how do I make the material less random so it looks better? any tips on that?

hello it depends what you mean by "reset", but for a cylinder you could use the Cylinder Projection

reset it as if there wasnt anything changed. I tried cylinder projection but it isn't same as it was at the first place

Like keyboard ctrl + Z?

yeh I guess but its too late. also my problem is fixed now

"Reset like nothing's changed", sure, but changed from what?
There is such a thing as a UV reset, under the menu UV > Reset. But what that does is make your UVs "factory new", aka each quadrilateral is stretched on the whole UV surface. Example with Suzanne:

That's rarely used for a reason, and I doubt that's what you want. You probably meant to go back to some form of previous state where the UVs were already "changed", but not manually tempered by you sectioning and moving UV elements around. With Suzanne again, it could mean how to go back to this:

In theory, all you have to do is to select all your UVs and run the unwrapping again with the same method and same settings as you did before.
Unwrapping doesn't keep the manual transforms you did on the UVs so you will always end up with the same result when running it with the same settings.
Seam unwrapping
If you made the UVs by yourself using UV seams (marking edges to be cut in the UV unwrapping) all you have to do is select all your UVs and press U to open the UV Mapping menu, and hit Unwrap, which by default would have the following options:

Since Blender 4.3, we got a new unwrapping method, so the UV Mapping menu will propose all of three of them to you in an Unwrapping sub-menu, followed (but separated by a line) by the other non-seam based methods:

Chose angle based for the previous default. But feel free to try Conformal or Minimum Stretch too.
Other projection methods
Other projection methods like project from view, Cube/Cylinder/Sphere projection, and Smart UV Project, will not follow your UV seams and will cut the UVs wherever they want. So If you use such a method, so long you didn't add/remove mesh parts, it will give the same UVs any time you run one of these and discard any manual modification that was done after.
Primitive and imported objects
The primitive objects of Blender (Suzanne, Cube, etc) and some imported meshes have UVs done by manually cutting UVs, but don't have any edges marked as seams. This is because UV seams are not a standard data we can find in exchange formats. If you run any form of unwrapping on them, you will definitely lose the UVs they had.
To avoid that, you can select all the UVs in the UV editor, and then go to the menu UVs > Mark Seams From Islands, effectively creating the seams you need to obtain the islands.
Then, you can run the unwrapping methods as seen in the above Seams section.  But for the case of imported objects, if their UVs were done in another software, you might not get exactly the same result in Blender just because their algorithm are different. There's no way around that.
Save UVs
A way to avoid all of this, though rarely so crucial to be even needed, is to never do any changed on your UVs without a duplicating it first in case you want to go back.
You can go in the Properties Editor > Mesh data tab > UV Map panel, use the +- buttons to add/remove UV Maps, set the active UV channel (the one used by default in shaders) with the camera icon, and any new  UV channel will be a duplcate of the one you have selected.

